# Oracle NVL problem

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to pass a null value as something else in my db and it seems to work without a `Where` clause like so

```
select NVL(column1, '0') column1 from table1
```

produces this

```
    0   test1
    0   test2   
    1   test3
```

But when I add the where clause like so

```
select NVL(column1, '0') column1 from table1 where column1 <=1
```

it produces this

```
    1   test3
```

But now if I add the following to the query it works

```
select NVL(column1, '0') column1 
from table1 
where NVL(column1, '0') <=1
```

But it seems like a long way round to get the value to show correctly with a `Where` clause

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot refer to an alias defined in the `SELECT` list from the `WHERE` clause.  So if you apply the `NVL` function in the `SELECT` list, you'd need the same function call in the `WHERE` clause (as you've demonstrated) or you would need to apply the function in an inline view

```
SELECT column1
  FROM (SELECT nvl(column1, 0) column1
          FROM table1)
 WHERE column1 <= 1
```

Note that for general sanity, if `COLUMN1` is a `NUMBER`, the second parameter to `NVL` should also be a `NUMBER`.  Otherwise, you're going to do implicit conversions and your comparison operations may end up using string comparison semantics rather than numeric comparison semantics.  Since the string '12' is less than the string '2', that can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

you have shown the correct way.

an alternative would be to say

```
OR column IS NULL
```